# How to determine if a product is part of a hidden collection in Shopify liquid templates?

Tags: shopify, liquid

is it possible to programmatically (in liquid templates) access the products contained in a hidden collection?  Or to find out if a particular product is in a hidden collection?  My attempts so far indicate that a collection that is hidden is not accessible via the collections global variable and I don't see another mechanism to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're right. If a collection is hidden, you're SOL. Kinda makes sense. If it's hidden, yet accessible, it's not really hidden. Imagine the outrage generated if a hidden collection was visible on a shop. People would circle the wagons for a burning...

Comment: Thanks David, that confirms my suspicion.  I've come up with another solution to my problem that makes more sense in the shopify way of things that doesn't require a collection.